# How to thank someone for following you back on social media?

Tags: translation, grammar

So, someone I respect has followed me back on social media, and I was hoping to thank them directly. I can't really figure out how to word "Thank you for following me"/"Thank you for following me back"/"Thank you for the follow". What's the best way I can say this?

Comment: 谢谢(你的)关注 / 感谢(你的)关注

Comment: @pogglings I know that this is your first question, but usually stack exchange requires that you show some homework - what you've done to try and answer the question yourself and why or how you are stuck. Otherwise your questions are gonna get downvoted and closed real quick. You can edit the question to fit the criteria to avoid any issues.

Comment: yeah, it's a good, specific question...  maybe you could do more to expand on why it is interesting/difficult based on your own research.....   avoid just "translate this"......  on that note,  maybe I could edit

Comment: Ahh I see! If I had known, I would've included more context - I thought It'd be weird/unnecessary if I gave the whole shebang, but I see now that it's a pretty important part of stack exchange. I've received many great answers and responded to the follower in question (ended up going with "谢谢你关注" as that's what many users, including my close friend who I asked at the very beginning, answered with) but I'll keep this in mind if I ever need help in the future. When I have the time, I'll get around to filling the details of my situation in the description.

Answer (score 1):

**谢谢你关注我呀！！！**

There's actually an article that kind of talks about this on [zhihu](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/o0v0o/20569063), funnily enough. Their translation there is:

> thank you follow me --> 谢谢你关注我呀！！！

They also have a picture of automated thanks for following me in action:

> [image: qqqfome]

On **social media** 关注 is always the term for *follow*.

Comment: I disagree. You can take 关注 as a type of follow, but can not make it vise versa.  "Thank you for following me back" does not ALWAYS mean "谢谢你关注我呀".

Comment: @dan OP is, clearly, only asking for situations on social media. So, yes, "Thank you for following me back" on **social media** does *always* mean "谢谢你关注我呀".

Comment: Even not *always* on social media. We just can't reach an agreement anyway.

Comment: @dan Please provide some examples then.

Comment: We have provided enough info for OP to use. I don't want to waste time on this any more. I'll just stop here.

Answer (score -2):

It could be 感谢大家(/你们)(长期以来一直)追随我、支持我!

感谢大家追随我: thank everyone/you for following me.

感谢大家支持我: thank everyone/you for supporting me.

感谢你们长期以来一直追随我、支持我: thank you for keeping following me and supporting me for such a long time.

> 感谢大家： thank everybody.
>
> 感谢你们： thank you.
>
> 长期以来一直： being for a long time;
>
> 追随我: follow me;
>
> 支持我：support me, back me;

Comment: Shouldn't it be 关注 like @JasonSwift mentioned in his comment and not 追随?

Comment: 关注 is more like you pay close attention to. But it could be possible to interpret it as following as well. It all depends what OP really want to address. We just provide more options here.

Comment: Dude, social media is always 关注 - to follow someone on weibo is 关注...to follow someone on zhihu is 关注... to follow a tieba on baidu is 关注 --- what's the issue here?

Comment: What about 追星？ You see young pursuit or follow their dreaming stars. Anyways, I will leave it there for OP to determine.

Comment: "关注" is widely used as the translation of "follow" on social media, and "粉" is a less serious alternative. "追随我" feels like "I'm the leader and you're subordinate", which is improper and misleading.

Comment: ---  vote it :)   don't forget to vote up or down, not only comment

Comment: I‘m not really sure about what OP really want to put or express. I also understand one of type of following on social media is to 关注 their Weibo or Tieba... But how would you say if people leave their messages to encourage when OP was depressed or buy a gift or 道具 to OP to support him/her? Isn't that another type of following or supporting. Since OP also says "Thank you for following me back", how would you interpret it? So I think the general term 追随 is suitable, meaning to follow a famous person. I just want OP to understand these terms, so he/she could use any of them accordingly.

Comment: Blindly having the faith to determine for OP is another type of misleading though.